# ANGULAR 11.1.4 ngFor not rendering images

Tags: arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ngfor

**Angular CLI: 11.1.4
Node: 12.18.3
OS: darwin x64**

.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProductImages().subscribe(image => {
        this.productImagesArray.push(image);
        this.productImagesArrayBackup = this.productImagesArray.shift()
    });
}

ionViewDidEnter() {
        console.log('images', this.productImagesArrayBackup);
    }
```

.html file

```
<ion-item-group *ngFor="let img of productImagesArrayBackup">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
                <ion-img [src]="'http://royalcare.pt/appi' + img"></ion-img>
            </ion-thumbnail>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-item-group>
```

console.log result

```
(3) ["/images/bata-em-polipropileno-.jpg", "/images/cinzeiro-de-parede.jpg", "/images/cinzeiro-de-pe.jpg"] length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

google chrome inspect element

```
<ion-item-group _ngcontent-mrh-c142="" role="group" class="ios item-group-ios item hydrated">
<ion-item _ngcontent-mrh-c142="" class="item ios ion-focusable hydrated">
<ion-thumbnail _ngcontent-mrh-c142="" slot="start" class="ios hydrated">
<ion-img _ngcontent-mrh-c142="" class="ios hydrated">
</ion-img></ion-thumbnail>
</ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
```

Why `*ngFor` does not render images in view?
Not even the `<ion-img>` tag has a `src=""` inside it.

Comment: Are you sure the image URL is correct? It looks wrong to me. Something like `"http://royalcare.pt/appi/./images/bata-em-polipropileno-.jpg"`. Are you sure you want that "dot" inbetween?

Comment: The image is incorrect it has a first dot that has to be removed, but the src="" attribute is missing in the element. What is causing this?

Comment: I put good images paths in the array and the result is the same. Error. No image is rendered.

Comment: You need to convert them to SafeUrl using DomSanitizer: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: Maybe it's problem with CSS, do you add width and height to `ion-img`  tag?